# Rename multiple lists items in for loop

Tags: r, list, rename

I have multiple list with the same amount of items. I want to rename all lists items in loop. For example from lists items names *"a, b, c"*, I want to rename them to *"first, second, third"*:

```
#create 3 lists with items names a, b, c
list1 <- list(a=c(1:10), b=c(1:5), c=c(1:3))
list2 <- list(a="a", b="b", c="c")
list3 <- list(a=runif(4), b=runif(2), c=runif(4))


# wanted names of list items 
names <- c("first", "second", "third")

new_list <- list()

for (i in 1:3){
  for(j in seq_along(names)) {
    n <- paste0(names[[j]])
    new_list[[n]] <-  assign(paste0("list_", i), get(paste0("list", i)))
  }
}
```

But the result rename only third list.. How should I rename all lists items at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply()` and `setNames()`:

```r
lapply(list(list1, list2, list3), \(x) setNames(x, names))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$first
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[1]]$second
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[1]]$third
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$first
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]$second
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> [[2]]$third
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]]$first
#> [1] 0.7475211 0.9317233 0.1603680 0.7952381
#> 
#> [[3]]$second
#> [1] 0.5450439 0.8351545
#> 
#> [[3]]$third
#> [1] 0.1782355 0.9909339 0.2366660 0.7104271
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Data from OP

```r
list1 <- list(a=c(1:10), b=c(1:5), c=c(1:3))
list2 <- list(a="a", b="b", c="c")
list3 <- list(a=runif(4), b=runif(2), c=runif(4))

names <- c("first", "second", "third")
```

We could also use a `for` loop with `setNames)()`:

```r
new_list <- list()

for (i in 1:3){
    new_list[[i]] <-  setNames(get(paste0("list", i)), names)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Put all lists into a list, loop through and assign new names, and put them back into environment, notice we are overwriting original lists:

```
names(list1)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"

list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^list")), 
                function(i) setNames(i, names)), globalenv())

names(list1)
# [1] "first"  "second" "third"
```